the sign of first and second order derivative of Hartree Fock energy in optimal damping algorithm
In the original paper of ODA, the gradient of RHF energy (given several lines below Eq. (1)) is $E^{\mathrm{RHF}}[D]=\mathrm{Tr}\{(2h+G[D])D\}$. By the spirit of ODA, we are interested in:
$$
\begin{align}
E^{\mathrm{RHF}}[D+\lambda\Delta D] &= \mathrm{Tr}\{(2h+G[D+\lambda\Delta D])(D+\lambda\Delta D)\} \\
&= E^{\mathrm{RHF}}[D]+\lambda(\mathrm{Tr}\{2h\cdot\Delta D\}+\mathrm{Tr}\{G[D]\cdot\Delta D\}+\mathrm{Tr}\{G[\Delta D]\cdot D\})+\lambda^2(G[\Delta D]\cdot\Delta D) \\
&= E^{\mathrm{RHF}}[D]+2\lambda(\mathrm{Tr}\{h\cdot\Delta D\}+\mathrm{Tr}\{G[D]\cdot\Delta D\})+\lambda^2(G[\Delta D]\cdot\Delta D) \\
&= E^{\mathrm{RHF}}[D]+2\lambda(\mathrm{Tr}\{F[D]\cdot\Delta D\})+\lambda^2(G[\Delta D]\cdot\Delta D),
\end{align}
$$
where $\mathrm{Tr}\{G[D]D^\prime\}=\mathrm{Tr}\{G[D^\prime]D\}$ and $F[D]\equiv h+G[D]$. The article further defined (2 is missed in $s$)
$$
\begin{align}
s &= 2\mathrm{Tr}\{F[D]\cdot\Delta D\} \\
c &= G[\Delta D]\cdot\Delta D,
\end{align}
$$
and gave the optimal damping criteria as
$$
\lambda_m=
\begin{cases}
1,& \text{if } c\le -s/2 \\
-s/2c,&\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
I thought this criteria is based on the fact that $s<0$ and $c>0$, which is mentioned but not proved in this work. I need to tackle this problem because in my calculations (for a different system) $c<0$ and I am trying to make clear the conditions under which $c>0$ holds.
Any help is warmly welcomed.
